# How to configure Kile to use a makefile?

Tags: makefile, latex, sweave

How do I tell Kile to use a makefile for the QuickBuild action?

**Some background:**

I have a sweave-project that I usually compile via a makefile. However, it's quite annoying having to switch between text editor and console every time I want to check if a sweave/latex code generates the output I want.

Thus, I recently looked into Kile. I like it so far, but I can't get Kile to compile sweave-code (QuickBuild for pure tex-file works; but if I try to build a sweave file, Kile tells me that `The document is not a latex root document. Continue anyway?`).

Comment: Have you googled this question? Does [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1749953) work for you?

Comment: Perhaps also look into an editor that can run your build for you. As at least both vim and emacs can do.

Comment: Have you got your preamble in the document you are compiling?

Answer (score 0):

The [instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1749953) given by [Roland Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219295/roland-smith) probably work well for you. Let me answer your initial question, how to use a makefile. I've just used the following steps successfully:

1. Create a new build tool (Settings > Configure Kile > Tools > Build > New). Name it as you want, use "Custom" class in the following dialoge box. When created and selected, enter `make` as Command on the right (General Tab) and special targets passed to make in Options. In Advanced tab select type: Run outside of Kile (rest probably irrelevant ie. ok by default).
2. Check your build tool works: Run it manually (Build > Other > ). If you don't find it in the other group, search in the other groups (compile, etc.). (Sidenote: The group should be controlled by Menu Tab > Add Tool to build menu option (cf. settings in 1), but that didn't work for my Kile version.) This should print (`Makefile` is my name for the build tool created in 1):

   ```
   [Makefile] d.tex (make)
   [Makefile] Done!
   ```
3. Create shortcut for your tool (optional): Settings > Configure Shortcuts, search for the name you provided and assign a shortcut.
4. Add your build tool to some existing (already shortcutted) toolchain (eg. QuickBuild with `Alt + 1`) (optional): Go to the menu of step 1 ((Settings > Configure Kile > Tools > Build), select QuickBuild and replace PDFLatex on the right by your newly created custom tool.